# How to update font awesome?

Tags: font-awesome

I help update seo stuff for uooutlands.com often font awesome comes up for misc page speed optimizations and i am not certain how to optimize the links to newer versions (i am not the designer)

I want to keep what they have but was curious if there are newer links to swap in thanks a ton!

I think some of these were the devs key:

https://use.fontawesome.com/f994eaf4bc.js

https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2

https://use.fontawesome.com/f994eaf4bc.css

“ Using CSS @import in an external stylesheet can add additional delays during the loading of a web page.
STYLESHEETS WITH @IMPORT STATEMENTS AND THE STYLESHEETS THEY IMPORT”

Also hoping it helps stay visible on load
“ Ensure text remains visible during webfont load”
https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2

Maybe start here?
https://fontawesome.com/download

Or here?

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Answer (score 0):

I my experience the fastest way to use FA is with Kits - but that would require an update to FA5 (or even 6 which currently is in beta-Stadium). The download-link you showed will not help, as that takes you to the current version (which raises the update-issue again).
You can find 4.7-related stuff at https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/

Comment: Thanks. Any way to regenerate it to a newer version without being the owner?

Comment: Well, you could upgrade - but that would require access (and edits) to the sources of the site.  (The cost of Pro is not out of the world, and if you're consulting, you might be able to sneak it into your invoices some way...)